# How to get Data at once

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am using the following query to get the data for one day in postgresql using jdbc .

```
  int[] days={1,2,3,4,5,6,9,12,18,24}

for(i=0;i<days.length;i++){
  //connect to database
    String sql="select id,extract ('day' from time) as day,count(*) as count from public.data where time>='2016-10-'"+days[i]+'06:00:00' and  time<='2016-10-"+days[i]+" 09:00:00' group by id,day ";
  //execute sql and close connection
}
```

The current query(one run in the loop) gives

```
id    day      count
___   ___      _____
 1     1         10
 2     1         12
 3     1         18
```

Like this it will give for each day.
But this is done for each day and I am writing the result set as a csv .Instead of that can I get the whole resulset which contains each day count during the period 6 to 9 instead of executing many sql statements?But I would like all at once like

```
id    day      count
___   ___      _____
 1     1         10
 2     1         12
 3     1         8
 1     2         10
 2     2         9
 3     2         18
 1     3         10
 2     3         12
 3     3         27
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single statement, no loop required:

```
select id,
       extract(day from time) as day,
       count(*) as count 
from public.data 
where extract(day from time) = any (array[1,2,3,4,5,6,9,12,18,24] ) 
  and time::date between date '2016-10-01' and date '2016-10-31'
  and time::time between time '06:00:00' and time '09:00:00'
group by id,day
```

---

<sup>I do hope `time` is not the real name of that column</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can use all in one using filter WHERE extract(day from time) in :days and extract(hour from time) between 6 and 8.

:days is used for parameter mapping in hibernate query, you can use equivalent of sql.

Answer (score 0):

**First** You have a problem in your query :

The date should be between two `''` and not `""`:

```
String sql="... where time>="2016-10-"+days[i]+"...
//--------------------------^--------^------------
```

Your query should look like this :

```
String sql="select id,extract ('day' from time) as day,count(*) as count 
            from public.data where time>='2016-10-"+days[i]+" 06:00:00' 
            and  time<='2016-10-"+days[i]+" 09:00:00' group by id,day ";
```

**Second** you have to not use Statement in can cause a syntax error or SQL Injection, instead you have to use PreparedStatement

Comment: You don't ever *have* to use batching.